# How to open http url in firebase functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

I have this url. Which basically sends a message in telegram with a bot when you paste it in the browser.

```
https://api.telegram.org/botsomeKEY/sendMessage?chat_id=-someID&text= TEST
```

My problem is that it is not letting me deploy this function and is giving me an error of "Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code".

```
export const sendMessage = functions.pubsub
.schedule("every 1 minutes") // run everyday "0 0 * * *" or every 1 minutes
.timeZone("America/Chicago")
.onRun((context) => {

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", httpAddress, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  return xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    text: "TEST",
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the logged messages above that error message, you should see what is causing your function to crash. In this case, it is likely your attempted use of `XMLHttpRequest()` which is not a native `node.js` API, but a browser API. While you could import a library such as [`xhr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr) to bring this to node, you are better off making use of a Promise-based networking API because the Firebase Functions SDK is also Promise-based. Examples of suitable libraries include [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), [`gaxios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaxios) and [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

`node-fetch` and `gaxios` are used internally by the Firebase SDK, so these are good choices.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

export const sendMessage = functions.pubsub
.schedule("every 1 minutes") // run everyday "0 0 * * *" or every 1 minutes
.timeZone("America/Chicago")
.onRun(async (context) => {
  const response = await fetch(httpAddress, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      text: "TEST"
    })
  });

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    // potential error (make sure to look out for other codes like 201-204, 301, 302)
    console.error(`Server responded with unexpected status code ${response.status}: ${await response.text()}`);
    return;
  }

  // Get response body and parse it as JSON
  const responseBody = await response.json();

  // do something with responseBody
  // see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
  
  console.log("Sent bot message successfully!");
});
```

Comment: thank you! I've been stuck on this for a while too. Also were you the one who sent the message through the bot? xD

Comment: yeah :D You've gotta be careful with stuff like that.